# Python hangman game, placing the letters in the right location

Tags: python

So basically I have a hangman game where I'm almost done, I just have to place the letter that the user guesses in the right location in the Graphics Window.

```
# Update the puzzle on the drawing window
#
# Input: A list containing the locations of the letter in the puzzle, the letter,
#        and the drawing window
# Output: None
def updatePuzzleDisplay(locations, letter, window):
```

So basically I have spaces that place themselves on the screen based on a random chosen word in a text file. I'm supposed to place the letter based on the location of the space. I also have to make sure it's placed in the right spot based on the word, and if a certain letter is repeated. 
Here is my space code.

```
# Draw the lines that represent each letter in the puzzle
#
# Input: The number of characters in the puzzle and the drawing window
# Output: None
def drawPuzzle(length, window):
    lines = Line(Point(15,275),Point(25,275))
    for index in range(length):
        newline = copy.copy(lines)
        newline.move(20,0)
        newline.draw(window)
```

I'm having trouble connecting the two, and need a bit of help. Also the parameter letter is the guess the user enters.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you are building this using graphics.py which was written for use with a specific text book and is extremely limited in scope.  if this is true you will need to method of targeting each line so you can call .undraw(window) on it and then draw a letter its place, or draw the letter just above the line and leave the line in place.  Either way you will need a way to target the specific position of the line which means each line will need to be individually identifiable.

Your question is probably to vague to get an answer.  As a starting point I would consider building an list(array) with each letter of the random word as an element of the list.  Coincide the line variable name with each index of the element.

then loop through the array to determine if the guessed letter is in the array and if so, act on the corresponding line...

You can use either the getCenter() or getP1()/getP2() methods of Line to get your coordinates for drawing the text to the window.

Hope this helps.